# SL4: Passing element in View as parameter to Command in ViewModel

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light, relaycommand

We have a user control with context menu on one of its child controls.
The Command is bound to a RelayCommand in the ViewModel.
However, the command has to act on another child control in the View.
What is the best way to do this?  I have tried passing the desired child control as a parameter, but I think the syntax is incorrect:

```
                        <Controls:ContextMenu >
                        <Controls:MenuItem Header="Center" >
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click" >
                                    <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand 
                                        Command="{Binding RecenterCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Controls:MenuItem>
                    </Controls:ContextMenu>
```

The command:

```
RecenterCommand = new RelayCommand<ScrollViewer>(Recenter);  
private void Recenter(ScrollViewer obj)  
{   
}
```

When I use the context menu, Recenter() is called, but the obj param is null.
What is the correct syntax for the ElementName attribute in the CommandParameter binding?

UPDATE:  I tried changing the CommandParameter to:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=scrollViewer}"
```

...but still doesn't work.

Thanks for any insights....

Comment: is your Element actually x:Name=scrollViewer?

Comment: Yes, it is:          <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to add PassEventArgsToCommand="True" so, the code will be like this:

```
<GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand  PassEventArgsToCommand="True":
                                    Command="{Binding RecenterCommand}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}" />
```

and if you want to cath the data in codebehind put (this is code from one of my programs used for a context menu item)

SelectedEmployer e = ((MenuItem)e).DataContext as Employer

I hope this will solve your problem, because you gave me a hint in how to solve one of my problems..

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I use RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>, the RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource is null.  When I try RelayCommmand<ScrollViewer> I can't use PassEventArgsToCommand - get an exception saying RoutedEventArgs can't be cast to ScrollViewer.

Comment: If I use RelayCommand<ScrollViewer> and the CommandParameter, the ScrollViewer param passed to the command is null.  That makes me wonder if the syntax in the CommandParameter is incorrect.